# which is more performant, <video> or <canvas> with video embed?

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas

I am developing a page with a full width / full height intro video `(100vw / 100vh)`, looks "full screen" until you scroll down.

Currently I am using HTML5 `<video>` to accomplish this, but I've noticed the page can get a little choppy, particularly while scrolling. The video is about 4mb.

Would I see an increase in performance if I were to replace the `<video>` with a `<canvas>`, and load the video frames directly through the canvas object instead? both elements are GPU accelerated so I'd figure it shouldn't make a difference, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why don't you test it? My gut feeling says the video should be better performing.

Comment: In your canvas scenario, what would be the source of your frames? If the frame source is a video element, then the canvas scenario would cost more resources because you're supporting both video and canvas. If the frame source is some buffered frames, then you will have to test the performance of buffering frames vs live video element. I'm guessing the live video element would be better again. It's a case of "best tool for the job". Video elements display video and canvas elements manipulate pixels.

Comment: If you want to have a customized video player, you should choose `<canvas>`. Otherwise, use `<video>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, all the cost of decoding a video frame is still there. Using a canvas would in addition to that add more cost, not less.

If the video is without sound you could temporary pause the video while scrolling, as well as pause it permanently when out of view:

```
var vt;
window.onscroll = function() {
    video.pause();                                  // pause video
    clearTimeout(vt);                               // clear timer
    vt = setTimeout(function() {                    // create a new timer
      var r = video.getBoudingClientRect();         // abs. bound
      if (window.scrollY < r.height) video.play();  // assumes video is in top
   }, 70);                                          // 70ms
    ...
};
```

Another key, although not of *very* much difference, is to make sure the video code is easy to decode. You can achieve this by removing noise, use flat colors and large surfaces, good lighting conditions, low depth-of-field to blur background as well as lower contrast and avoid too many details in the main subject(s) (this will also produce smaller files).

```js
var video = document.querySelector("video"),
    vt;

window.onscroll = function() {
  video.pause();
  clearTimeout(vt);
  vt = setTimeout(function() {
    var r = video.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (window.scrollY < r.height) video.play();
  }, 70);
};
```

```css
html, body {width:100%; height: 2000px}
video {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<video muted width="500" height="280" autoplay="true">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```